# Checking if in a table in mysql are two rows with the same elements

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say we have the tables: table0 and table1.
In both table0 and table1 we store a name, age, and date.

How can I check if an entry from table0 and an entry from table1 have the same name and age?

Answer (score 0):

Simple take join with where clause t1.name = t2.name and t1.age = t2.age.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to "MINUS" or "EXCEPT" depending on the flavor of SQL used by your DBMS.

```
select * from table0
minus
select * from table1
```

If the query returns no rows then the data is exactly the same.

Comment: MINUS and EXCEPT are not supported by MySql.